# Finding intermediate Lattitude Longitude between two given points

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gps, google-maps-markers

I am provided with this information -

1. Lat-Long of source
2. Lat-Long of destination

I need to find the Lat-Long pairs on the path from source to destination. These Lat-Long pairs must differ from each other by some given granularity.

Is there some Google API using which I can get this information ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation

Comment: @Shark I want Lat-Long pairs of the _actual_ path, that is the path on which I can move via road and reach from source to destination.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find a geographic point between two other points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676845/how-to-find-a-geographic-point-between-two-other-points)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Google Maps API Elevation Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/elevation) does exactly that. Given a path (defined by your source and destination LatLng pair), you also specify the number of samples and it will return elevation for specific LatLng points along that path. Just ignore the elevation information.

The [Elevation Web Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/) is available for use separate from the Google Maps API v3. However make sure that your usage still falls within the [terms of service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms).

To retrieve granular points along a driving path, use the Google Maps API Directions Service to obtain the full driving path and use that path as the input to the Elevation Service.

Comment: Chad, I want Lat-Long pairs of the _actual_ path, that is the path on which I can move via road and reach from source to destination. You sure this is what this API returns ?

Comment: Yes. If you want a path that follows a road, then you need to pass the full path information to the elevation service and not just the source and destination. You can retrieve the driving path using the directions service.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the directions api from google
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

You give it the origin and destination and then specify your travelmode (which is car by default but you can also say you are walking or using transit)