# Finding intermediate latitude and longitude in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, cordova

I have the following data.
1.source name.
2.destination name.
I need to find lat-long pairs on the path  from source to destination.Is there any google Api available for it??. I refered this questions [Finding intermediate Lattitude Longitude between two given points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299875/finding-intermediate-lattitude-longitude-between-two-given-points) but can't understand the whole thing.Can any one have simpler answer for this ?

**EDIT**
here is what i am tried

```
 //store lat and long
    var sd_array=[];
        $('#processbtn').click(function(e){
    //get source and destination name       
                var source=$('#source').val();
                var destination=$('#destination').val();
                if(source==''||destination==''){
                    alert("all fields required");
                }else{
                   //decode lat-long from address
                    getLatitudeAndLongitude(source);
                    getLatitudeAndLongitude(destination);
                }
            });
        function getLatitudeAndLongitude(address){
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
              if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
               //store to array
                sd_array.push(latitude);
                sd_array.push(longitude);
              }
            }); 
        }
    function getInterMediateLatLong(sd_array){
      //get intermediate locations 
      /*sd_array[0] source lat
      sd_array[1] source long
      sd_array[2] destination lat
      sd_array[3] destination long*/
    }
```

i need the help to achieve get intermediate locations.

Comment: How many "intermediate points" you need, only one?  What you not understand in [the Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/)? It is  a typical [XY plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system) problem, you have points A,B and need a set of points betweem them.

Comment: 3 to 5 pairs needed also I am new to google map APIs

Answer (score 1):

Since the type underlying each of lat and lon is real (AKA double or float) simply add the source and end-point variables and divide each result by 2.0 .

```
var mid_lat = (lat_source + lat_dest ) / 2.0 ;
var mid_lon = (lon_source + lon_dest ) / 2.0 ;
```

Then the coordinates of the mid-point are mid_lat, mid_lon .

Comment: I Can't understand what you mean

Answer (score 1):

You must understand first that it is a [Mathematical problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system), but is simple. Google will return a set o XY points... The procedure is:

1. Express correctly the "reference points" *S* and *D*, the *S*ource and the *D*estination points. So *Sx,Sy,Dx,Dy*. They are not "names", are XY coodenates (!).
2. Check how to say to Google-API how many points you need
3. submit your query to Google-API:  **Edit your question to show your query (Javascript code) to us!** them we can discuss here.

---

You need to express

```
{path[]: LatLngPathes, samples: 4}
```

Javascript fragment example to obtain `LatLngPathes`:

```
 var source = new google.maps.LatLng(36.578581, -118.291994);
 var destination = new google.maps.LatLng(36.606111, -118.062778);
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.let me try it

Comment: Sir I have edited my question please take look at this