# getting lat long along the calculated direction in google maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, maps

Is it possible to get lat long along the calculated route from google maps API. For instance, If I search for direction from A to B is it possible to get lat long of the calculated route at every x interval of distance ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding intermediate Lattitude Longitude between two given points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299875/finding-intermediate-lattitude-longitude-between-two-given-points)

Answer (score 0):

The [Elevation Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/elevation) returns latlng values at intervals along a path. You provide it with an array of latlng values which define your path and the number of samples you want.